# Jupyter notebook will not open from cmd

Tags: jupyter-notebook, command-prompt, windows-11

I downloaded Jupyter from Python 3.11 (not anaconda). It showed requirement already satisfied.
When a try to open jupyter notebook from cmd it shows the following error:

[image]

What do I do?

How to set the PATH? Please provide steps. I am not a coder.